# ASP.Net MVC Pager helper and view not working together - what should I put in my views first line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm following the example here: http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part8.htm and trying to add a pager to my app.

In my controller I have:

```
    // GET: /Offer/
    // GET: /Offer/Page/2

    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        const int pageSize = 10;
        var items = db.Customers.OrderByDescending(x => x.OfferCreatedOn);
        var paginatedItems = new PaginatedList<Customer>(items, page ?? 0, pageSize);
        return View(paginatedItems);
    }
```

I have a helper folder, with this helper in it:

```
   public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
   {

    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        TotalCount = source.Count();
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / (double)PageSize);

        this.AddRange(source.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 0);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex + 1 < TotalPages);
        }
    }
}
```

Where I'm now stuck, is what to put into the top of my View.

If I put in: `@model PaginatedList<FGBS.Models.Customer>` - then I get error messages advising:

PaginatedList does not contain a definition for "HasPreviousPage" (which is in the helper), and also for other items which are in my Customer model (which should be passed to the view too).

If I change the first line of the view to: `@model FGBS.Helpers.PaginatedList<Customer>` then I get the type or namespace 'Customer' cannot be found, with the following line hilighted:

public class _Page_Views_offer_index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage>

Thanks for any insight,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
@model FGBS.Helpers.PaginatedList<FGBS.Models.Customer>
```